# Would this regex be multibyte safe?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, multibyte

I'm using the following regex to check an image filename only contains alphanumeric, underscore, hyphen, decimal point:

```
preg_match('!^[\w.-]*$!',$filename)
```

This works ok. But I have concerns about multibyte characters. Should I specifically handle them to prevent undetermined errors, or should this regex reject mb filenames ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP does not have "native" support for multibyte characters; you need to use the ["mbstring" extension<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) (which may or may not be available). Furthermore, it would appear that there is no way to create a "multibyte-character string", as such -- rather, one chooses to treat a native string as multibyte-character string by using special "mbstring" functions. In other words, a PHP string does not know its own character encoding -- you have to keep track of it manually.

You may be able to get away with it so long as you use UTF-8 (or similar) encoding. UTF-8 always encodes multibyte characters to "high" bytes (for instance, `ß` is encoded as `0xcf 0x9f`), so PHP will probably treat them just like any other character. You would not be able to use an encoding that might potentially encode a multibyte character into "special" PHP bytes, such as `0x22`, the "double-quote" symbol.

The only regular expression functions in PHP that know how to deal with specific multibyte characters out of a range of multiple character-sets are [`mb_ereg`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/mb_ereg), [`mb_eregi`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/mb_eregi), [`mb_ereg_replace`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/mb_ereg_replace) and [`mb_eregi_replace`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/mb_eregi_replace).

PCRE based regular expression functions like [`preg_match`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/preg_match) support UTF-8 by using the [`u`-modifier (PCRE8)<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

But of course, as described above PHP strings don't know their own encoding, so you first need to instruct the "mbstring" library using the mb_regex_encoding function. Note that that function specifies the encoding of the string you're matching, not the string containing the regular expression itself.

Comment: thanks for the info, multibyte encoding could certainly be easier in php I feel.